# matplotlib documentation: unexplained paremeters in methods and constructors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to both Python and matplotlib, but am not new to software engineering. I have found learning matplotlib harder than need be due to a perceived lack of documentation. For example, I wish to create an Axes object by directly calling the constructor. From the documentation, I have:

```
class matplotlib.axes.Axes(fig, rect, axisbg=None, frameon=True, sharex=None, sharey=None, label='', xscale=None, yscale=None, **kwargs)
```

(Taken from http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/axes_api.html)

The parameter `fig` is quite self-explanatory, but `rect` is less so (what are the units, which order are they given in, etc). Searching through the superclasses of `Axes` doesn't yield anything useful. This is one of many similar examples, where parameters are not being documented.

My question is: am I missing some documentation? Is this genuinely due to a lack of documentation, or am I missing something?

I should emphasise that I'm not making a general complaint about the matplotlib documentation ([GOOD matplotlib documentation recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872802/good-matplotlib-documentation-recommendation)), but am asking if I'm missing documentation, and if not, how other matplotlib users circumvent this lack of documentation? In particular, I'm focussing on unexplained parameters in constructors and methods.

Thanks!

Comment: My impression is that the less used objects and functions are documented less thoroughly. If you encounter such a function you might want to consider whether you need it and if you are taking the right approach. However, the parameter you mention could definitely be explained better in the documentations.

Comment: First, python does not really have constructors.  Second, you should not be creating `Axes` objects directly, you should be creating them using the methods in `pyplot`, `mpl_toolkits`, or hanging off of figure objects.  There is a lot of internal plumbing that needs to be set up when you create an `Axes` that 99.99% of users shouldn't worry about.